# Python: index 5324 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5040

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a Python code which reads 5040 values from a TXT file to perform a simulation, as shows this partial code:

```
### Starting iteration
h=0.001
for v_capt in v_capt_list:
    print 'Capture velocity =',v_capt, 'm*(s^-2)'
    print 'Fraction of atoms already below the capture velocity =',(F(v_capt)-F(0.0))*100, '%'

    for I in I_list:  
        v_final_3D=[[],[],[],[]]
        result_3D=[[],[],[]]

        for J in J_list:    
            Bfield = ZSField*J

            for det in det_list:
                result=0.0
                for v_min in v_class:
                    s = 0.0
                    v = v_min
                    while s <= 0.524 and v >= 0.0:     # MOT position in the magnetic field files
                        k1=[v,a_function(det,I,v,B(s))]
                        k2=[v+k1[1]*h/2.0,a_function(det,I,v+k1[1]*h/2.0,B(s+k1[0]*h/2.0))]
                        k3=[v+k2[1]*h/2.0,a_function(det,I,v+k2[1]*h/2.0,B(s+k2[0]*h/2.0))]
                        k4=[v+k3[1]*h,a_function(det,I,v+k3[1]*h,B(s+k3[0]*h))]
                        s=s+h/6.0*(k1[0]+2.0*k2[0]+2.0*k3[0]+k4[0])
                        v=v+h/6.0*(k1[1]+2.0*k2[1]+2.0*k3[1]+k4[1])
                    if v <= v_capt and v > 0.0:
                        result=result+F((v_min)+((v_step)/2.0))-F((v_min)-((v_step)/2.0))

                    v_final_3D[0].append(J)
                    v_final_3D[1].append(det)
                    v_final_3D[2].append(v_min)
                    v_final_3D[3].append(v)

                    result_3D[0].append(J)
                    result_3D[1].append(det)
                    result_3D[2].append(result)
```

Then, the code creates a function called *B(s)*, as you can see below (I skipped part of the code between the first and this second code).

```
### Reading Magnetic Field Files
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
# Zeeman slower's file
ZSFile=open(path+'\DyZSField(G)_1A_range354mm_5040points.txt','r')
ZSField = np.array([])
while True:
    line = ZSFile.readline()
    if line == '':
        break
    ZSField=np.append(ZSField,[float(line)])
ZSFile.close()

# Magnetic field as a function of position in meters
def B(s):
    dBds = (Bfield[int(math.ceil(s*1e4))]-    Bfield[int(math.floor(s*1e4))])/1.0e-4 # Gauss*(m^-1)
    return Bfield[int(math.floor(s*1e4))]+dBds*(s-math.floor(s*1e4)*1e-4)
```

However, when I run the code, the Python Shell shows the error message `IndexError: index 5324 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5040` (see the following image).

[image: Error message]

I found similar errors, but no answer could solve my problem. Can you help me?

Thank you very much, Marcos Miotti

Comment: add many `print()` to see where and when you get `5324`. Using `float` numbers you can get inaccurate values.

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks, Furas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem: the program try to search on the TXT file a value at the 5324th position, but there is only 5040 numbers. Thereby, I reduced the `s` value a bit. On the first code above, I wrote

```
while s <= 0.524 and v >= 0.0:     # MOT position in the magnetic field files
```

Then, I just change to

```
while s <= 0.50 and v >= 0.0:     # MOT position in the magnetic field files
```

For my code's purpose, that solution worked well. **:)**